# How to show data by formatting string into django templates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms, django-templates

Here i am creating a blog and formatting some content bold as show below:
[image]

on a detail page that text is showing me like this:
[image]

how to fix it and change its format ,

in form.py ,

```
class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ('tag',"title","image_data","body",)

        widgets ={
            'title' : forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'editable medium-editor-textarea blogtitle'}),
            'body':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'editable medium-editor-textarea postcontent'})
        }
```

in post detail page i am adding following lines in head tags :

```
 <!-- Medium Style Editor -->

    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/medium-editor@latest/dist/js/medium-editor.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/medium-editor@latest/dist/css/medium-editor.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
```

blog_form.html

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
<h1>Create a new blog</h1>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value='Publish' class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
</form>
</div>
<script>var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable');</script>
```

Comment: Please include more details in your question. For example, are you using a CMS or where are you editing the content? How are you rendering the text? Why did you tag jquery? etc.

Comment: I have added all the details in my question , and the reason tag jquery because i think this is more front end problem rather than back end ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django [HTML escapes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/#automatic-html-escaping) template values to protect against [cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

If you're only going to have trusted users who can edit your fields, you can use the [`safe` template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) to turn off HTML escaping.